# sqlite is not Getting Updated

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sqlite

this is my app.config

```
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DataBaseEntity"  connectionString="metadata=res://*/DBModel.csdl|res://*/DBModel.ssdl|res://*/DBModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SQLite;provider connection string=&quot;data  source=I:Sompepath\dbfilename&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

and below is the usage

```
 using (var context = new DataBaseEntity("name=DataBaseEntity"))
            {
                context.Connection.Open();
                var status = delegatefunction(context);
                if (status)
                {
                    context.AcceptAllChanges();
                    context.SaveChanges(SaveOptions.DetectChangesBeforeSave);
                    context.Connection.Close();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
```

the delegate function looks like this

```
(context =>{var abc = new xyz();                
            context.xyzs.AddObject(abc);});
```

the database is not having the data which is just added in the delegate

and there is no exception in the application

the connection object in the context looks like this

[image: the database and datasource are empty]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `context.AcceptAllChanges();` That call is telling EF that there are no pending changes so the `SaveChanges` has nothing to save to database because it believes that all changes were already saved.

`AcceptAllChanges` in normally called inside the `SaveChanges` once all modifications are correctly saved to the database. This method is public to support some complex scenarios where you want to save modifications on [multiple context within single transaction](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/01/11/savechanges-false.aspx).